# c++: how to remove surrogate unicode values from string?

Tags: c++, unicode, replaceall, surrogate-pairs

how do you remove surrogate values from a std::string in c++?
looking for regular expression like this:

```
string pattern = u8"[\uD800-\uDFFF]";
regex regx(pattern);
name = regex_replace(name, regx, "_");
```

how do you do it in a c++ multiplatform project (e.g. cmake).

Comment: Your edit has changed the semantics of the question, and the title no longer matches the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you can't store UTF-16 surrogates in a `std::string` (`char`-based), you would need `std::u16string` (`char16_t`-based), or `std::wstring` (`wchar_t`-based) on Windows only.  Javascript strings are UTF-16 strings.

For those string types, you can use either:

- [`std::remove_if()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) + [`std::basic_string::erase()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase):

  ```cpp
  #include <string>
  #include <algorithm>

  std::u16string str; // or std::wstring on Windows
  ...
  str.erase(
      std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(),
          [](char16_t ch){ return (ch >= 0xd800) && (ch <= 0xdfff); }
      ),
      str.end()
  );
  ```
- [`std::erase_if()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase2) (C++20 and later only):

  ```cpp
  #include <string>

  std::u16string str; // or std::wstring on Windows
  ...
  std::erase_if(str,
      [](char16_t ch){ return (ch >= 0xd800) && (ch <= 0xdfff); }
  );
  ```

---

**UPDATE**: You edited your question to change its semantics.  Originally, you asked how to *remove* surrogates, now you are asking how to *replace* them instead.  You can use [`std::replace_if()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace) for that task, eg:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

std::u16string str; // or std::wstring on Windows
...
std::replace_if(str.begin(), str.end(),
    [](char16_t ch){ return (ch >= 0xd800) && (ch <= 0xdfff); },
    u'_'
);
```

Or, if you really want a regex-based approach, you can use [`std::regex_replace()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_replace), eg:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <regex>

std::wstring str; // std::basic_regex does not support char16_t strings!
...
std::wstring newstr = std::regex_replace(
    str,
    std::wregex(L"[\\uD800-\\uDFFF]"),
    L"_"
);
```

Comment: I was under the impression that you can store strings with any encoding in `std:: string` or `char[]` , it's just that when you manipulate them you need specialized functions to interpret them in the  specified encoding. Or is that true only for ANSI and UTF-8?

Comment: is it safe to use u16string in a multiplatform cmake project?

Comment: @bolov You can store raw binary bytes in a `std::string`, so yes, you could technically store a UTF-16 codeunit sequence in the memory of a `std::string`, but manipulating that data would be harder than if you had just used a proper UTF-16 string type to begin with.

Comment: @RashidMousavyKhoshrou since `std::u16string` is a standard string type since C++11, I would assume yes for any C++11 compliant compiler/build chain.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes, that makes sense.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for the answer, I have to check this on windows, linux and mac. but right now seems compiler not accepting this regular expression u"[\uD800-\uDFFF]" on windows I get C3850 error, on ubuntu also not compiled. do you use a  special option?

Comment: @RashidMousavyKhoshrou [Compiler Error C3850](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c3850) says: "*Characters represented as universal character names must represent valid Unicode code points in the range 0-10FFFF. **A universal character name cannot contain a value in the Unicode surrogate range, D800-DFFF**, or an encoded surrogate pair.*" This is also echoed in [String and character literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/string-and-character-literals-cpp#surrogate-pairs).

Comment: @RashidMousavyKhoshrou Also, it turns out `std::basic_regex` does not support `char16_t` strings anyway yet. So, I have updated my example.

Comment: As I see strings are tricky when it comes to multi platform development. people are taking about don't using wide char strings and as I checked wide chars have different sizes on different platforms. is there a general multiplatform string solution here or I have to back to std::string ?

Comment: @RashidMousavyKhoshrou There are plenty of 3rd party Unicode libraries that are cross platform.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thank you Remy, its been like 20 years since I code in c++. can you name best lightweight string options for multiplatform c++ development.

Comment: @RashidMousavyKhoshrou "best" is subjective. And asking for recommendations is off-topic for StackOverflow anyway. Do some research, try out some options for yourself, and see what works for your situation.